# asp.net - application state reliability

Tags: asp.net, caching

I'm considering relying on the asp.net application state in a web application.

I have it being populated when the application starts with some very important values (301 redirects, url rewrites).

Any time the application restarts, it gets populated just fine.

Are there any particular reasons why the app state might get cleared or corrupted that I should know about?

Is it safe for me to assume that the values in the app state are safe unless manually removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cache is generally meant to be temporary.  it sounds Application State is a better fit for your needs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx

Comment: sorry, i stated my question poorly. i am using the app state.

Comment: then you're good to go.  asp.net itself stores a bunch of things in app sate.